# SELECT father + his child + childs books sorted by nPages

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

fathers table

```
id     name    age    married
9      Max     45     1
```

Childrens table

```
id    father_id    name 
12       9         Rose
```

Books table

```
id    owner_id   title            nPages
1        12       Harry potter    755
2        12       JDK             124
```

I tried with

```
Select father.*, child.*, books.*
FROM fathers father
LEFT JOIN children child
    ON child.father_id = father.id
LEFT JOIN books book
    ON book.owner_id = child.id
WHERE father.married = 1
LIMIT 1
```

Which returns father and child + **only one book**. But I need all the books the child owns sorted by nPages.

Something like this:

```
[
  name : MAX , 
  age : 45, 
  married : 1, 
  child => [
     father_id => 9, 
     name => Rose, 
     books => [
        book1 => ..., 
        book2 => ...
     ]

  ]
]
```

Could you please help me?

NOTE! a father can have only one child.

Comment: Are you expecting the query to return some kind of json? :)

Comment: No, but conver the result array to json using json_encode.

Comment: You have to divide the problem in two: first write a query to count the number of books per child, then use it as a subquery to get the desired result.

Comment: No mysql query will return json encoded result. First, work on the query. Then find your way to represent the data in the application (PHP, in your case) level.

Comment: How does father.married = 1 help achieving the results (based on the title of this question)

Comment: Title has been adjusted for those who didnt read the questions text. Im sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried anything like this..

```
SELECT
    father.name AS fatherName,
    child.name AS childName,
    COUNT(books.owner_id) AS bookCount
FROM
    books
    INNER JOIN child ON books.owner_id = child.id
    INNER JOIN father ON child.father_id = father.id
GROUP BY
    books.owner_id
ORDER BY
    bookCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Updated (not checked)

```
SELECT
    father.name AS fatherName,
    child.name AS childName,
    books.title AS bookName,
    books.nPages AS pageCount
FROM
    books
    INNER JOIN child ON books.owner_id = child.id
    INNER JOIN father ON child.father_id = father.id
WHERE 
    books.id IN
                (
                    SELECT
                          books.id
                    FROM 
                          books
                    GROUP BY
                          books.owner_id
                    ORDER BY
                          COUNT(books.owner_id) DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                )
ORDER BY
    books.nPages DESC
```

Final Update (Not checked)

```
SELECT
    father.name AS fatherName,
    child.name AS childName,
    books.title AS bookName,
    books.nPages AS pageCount
FROM
    child
    INNER JOIN father ON child.father_id = father.id
    INNER JOIN books ON books.owner_id = child.id
WHERE 
    child.id IN
                (
                    SELECT
                          books.owner_id
                    FROM 
                          books
                    GROUP BY
                          books.owner_id
                    ORDER BY
                          COUNT(books.owner_id) DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                )
ORDER BY
    books.nPages DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  He wants the "child who has the most books".  Your solution just gets the one with the highest owner_id.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally used owner_id (instead of bookCount) in ORDER clause. Should be working.

Comment: The issue is that this will limit on only 1 row and also the OP needs all books for the father that has the child with the most books.

Comment: Title of your question was a bit misleading. I'll update my answer very shortly.

Comment: J A. Yes the title was misleading. Im sorry for that however the description was clear.

Comment: I am not sure if I got the question right. If a father (x) has two children (a,b) and if 'a' has 15 books (highest) and 'b' has 5 books. Should the query output x -> a -> 15 or x -> a,b -> 15,5 or x->20?

Comment: Lets say a father can have only one child! I may fix it by my self later on when it comes to 2 children!

Comment: Yes. 1st update would NOT return valid results if same book (within the result) is owned by other children.

Answer (score 2):

I just don't remember if MySQL allows you to add a limit to an `IN` clause... but you let me know:

```
SELECT f.*, b.*, c.* FROM books b
JOIN children c ON b.owner_id = c.id
JOIN fathers f ON c.father_id = f.id
WHERE c.id in (
    SELECT owner_id from books
    GROUP BY owner_id
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY b.nPages
```

This should work for any amount of childs.

Comment: Have you checked this? I mean, id in books table does not seem to be linked to anything.

Comment: No I haven't (I don't have the schema :) But as you said, it is not id but `owner_id` what I meant. Updated.

Comment: Your query is better than mine. (Except I don't understand count(*) for this situation)

Comment: No better, no worse... just different. `Count(*)` will count the rows, while `count(field)` will count the rows which have a not null `field`. In this case, having a `count(owner_id)` would be the same as it doesn't make sense that there will be books without an owner. If there were and they happened to be the majority, then the inner select would return just a `null` value. If using `count(owner_id)` then all the null ones would be omitted from the count and a non-null `owner_id` would be returned.